# How to test a CT Sensor (Alternating Current Clamp)?

Tags: current, ac, current-measurement, current-transformer

I recently purchased a CT clamp. I am left wondering what the best way is to test this in a laboratory environment, specifically with an AC current generator. I just want to know whether the device works properly.

Could I just generate a fixed amount of AC current from the generator and short my negative and positive wires to create a current loop? From this, could I then just clamp my CT sensor around this loop?

If not, I am open to more suggestions! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,

Hashim Shamsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an accurate AC ammeter you can find a reasonably steady, reasonable resistive load (perhaps a heat lamp, for example) that is somewhere between half and full scale of the probe, run **one** of the AC wires through the probe, through the ammeter, and compare the probe output to the AC ammeter.

If you can only find a load that is (say) between 1/4 and 1/2 or between 1/6 and 1/3 etc. you can thread multiple turns through the clamp-on probe to multiply the effective current.

It is essential that the turns are from **one** side of the AC and are only threaded through in one direction, otherwise they will cancel.

Comment: Thanks I guess this makes sense! I should be able to find a resistive load fairly easily to carry this out.

Answer (score 0):

Take a resistive load of known value (say, a small space heater that lacks a fan), and use the CT on the hot wire going to it, hooked up to a meter.  You should be able to get clamp adapters that plug into an outlet and break hot and neutral out to the two "arms" before coming back together into a socket, as depicted below in a representative North American version, at an electrical supply house or even a home-improvement/hardware store.

[image: ac line splitter adapter]

Once you have everything set up, you should be able to use the docs for your CT to convert your meter reading to a current reading, then match that up with the nameplate wattage on your load. (space heater, electric griddle, what have you)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have read the manual yet or even the wiki notes.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_clamp#Clamp_meter

Calibration requires standards. If your range is variable then try all known current sources you have ( such as your 50 Ohm generator into a 50 Ohm load) then sweep and see what errors are found. Be aware of DC and degaussing.